# jQuery Table Sorting by Attr e.g. Title

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know of a jQuery plugin that allows table sorting when clicking on the header, but checks say the title of a cell and sorts by that before looking at the contents of the cell?

I have some data in my cells such as 3h 5m and 5m, most sorting plugins get these in the wrong order as it sorts it alphanumerically because it doesn't understand the value.

I am sure somewhere I have seem a plugin where you put the raw data in the title, and the plugin actually sorted based on that data rather than the info in the cell.

Many thanks for your time,

Comment: jQuery [`datatables`](http://datatables.net/) has support for [custom sorting functions](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting#functions_type)

Comment: See http://servers.gamingsociety.co.uk/mc/players for where I am at so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery dataTables and the following custom sorting function (you may have to expand it if your "last seen" has more than just days/hours/minutes):

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['mytime-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    var regex = /\s*(?:(\d+)d)?\s*(?:(\d+)h)?\s*(?:(\d+)m)?\s*/;
    var m;

    m = a.match(regex);
    var x = (m[1] ? parseInt(m[1]) : 0) * 1440 + (m[2] ? parseInt(m[2]) : 0) * 60 + (m[3] ? parseInt(m[3]) : 0);

    m = b.match(regex);
    var y = (m[1] ? parseInt(m[1]) : 0) * 1440 + (m[2] ? parseInt(m[2]) : 0) * 60 + (m[3] ? parseInt(m[3]) : 0);

    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['mytime-desc']  = function(a,b) {
    // Same function as above, except for the return value:
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
}
```

And the associated jQuery dataTable call would look something like:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "sType": "mytime" },
        null
    ]
});
```

Comment: Currently throwing: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fnSetData' of undefined
Ojquery.dataTables.min.js:120
$jquery.dataTables.min.js:50
i.fn.dataTablejquery.dataTables.min.js:151
e.extend.eachjquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
e.fn.e.eachjquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
i.fn.dataTablejquery.dataTables.min.js:139
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort.mytime-ascplayers:19
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWithjquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
e.extend.readyjquery-1.6.4.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.C

Comment: Neither can I something to do with jQuery itself, definitely part of your custom search, small look into it!

Comment: Make sure that each column has a header.  Even if you have a header row with some colspans in it, I think that you need to add ANOTHER header row with individual header for those that were "covered" under a colspan.  If what I said doesn't make sense, check the HTML of this example: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Comment: John's comment above is right: the number of ths in thead has to match the number of tds.